# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException UIPageController Crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uipageviewcontroller

[image: Please check Crash image here]I am getting this crash in firebase but unable replicate in my own device i have used uipageviewcontroller

i have tried many scenarios but unable to regenerate but firebase gives this crash everytime